# Custom Include Function

Tags: php

I'm getting a bit better than I used to be with functions and class and well. PHP in general. I cannot find anything anywhere on how I could possibly do this however, essentially what I'm after is I have a directory html. inside is themes, assets and all your other goodies offered. The themes is where the main php file is that loads when you go to the site, but sometimes you have to include a file from the theme itself. 
For that my idea is to set the path for the theme

```
class CSite { 
public $db;
public $sitesettings = array(
    'host'      => "192.168.176.128",
    'path'  => "themepath",
    'Sitename'  => 'My Theme',
    'Copyright' => YourCopyright,
);

public function __construct() {
    $this->sitename = $this->sitesettings['Sitename'];
    $this->host = $this->sitesettings['host'];
    $this->path = $this->sitesettings['path'];
    $this->protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
    $this->rootpath = root_path.'/';
    $this->themepath = 'themes/'.$this->sitesettings['path'].'/';
    $this->copyright = $this->sitesettings['Copyright'].'<br />Proudly Powered By Doxramos CMS';
    $this->db = new db();

}
public function ThemeInclude() {
include_once($theme->path);
}
```

But the part I'm not sure how I could finish or even know where to start is say they have a functions.php file in the theme. I want the syntax in the theme folder to be something along the lines of

```
$Site = new CSite();
$Site->ThemeInclude('functions.php');
```

And from there it would run `include_once($theme->path.'/functions.php');`

Does anyone have any starting points that I could go with on this?

Comment: Are you asking about function parameters? `public function ThemeInclude($file) { include_once($theme->path . '/' . $file); }`

Comment: It's really hard to understand your goal. Can you try to explain it better?

Comment: Actually that was exactly what I was trying to accomplish Niet. Sorry; I wasn't entirely sure how to word it. I didn't want to ask how to create an include function because I felt that that would actually just get ridiculed with it already exists.